# Nokogiri help XPath not working

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Trying to pull one tiny bit of text from very large HTML doc. However no matter what method of striping the HTML to get to the text I want, it still pulls all the HTML.

The part of the the HTML I am trying to pull is below. All I want is the text between the `< a >< /a >` tags

```
<div id="countDetails_main">
<table id="countLevelDetailsTable" class="display" align="center" border="1" frame="void">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th>Bin Id</th>
            <th>Created By User Id</th>
            <th>Creation Date</th>
            <th>Process Id</th>
            <th>Process Name</th>
            <th>Bin Status</th>
            <th>Counting Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <tr id="process-1">

                <td>
                    <a href="#" onclick="if (prepareLineItemDetailPane('process-1')) { initiateAjaxCall('process-1','-1'); }; return false;">
                        P-1-Z100D4
                    </a>
                </td>

                <td>jsickle</td>
                <td>Aug/21/2014-08:17:13</td>
                <td>433332</td>
                <td>AdHoc Process</td>
                <td>Count in process</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="process-2">

                <td>
                    <a href="#" onclick="if (prepareLineItemDetailPane('process-2')) { initiateAjaxCall('process-2','78856256'); }; return false;">
                        R-1-P110B680
                    </a>
                </td>

                <td>josephir</td>
                <td>Sep/12/2014-19:25:08</td>
                <td>433332</td>
                <td>AdHoc Process</td>
                <td>Count in process</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
            </tr>
```

Ruby code as of now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url ='http://secretwebsite.com/site/report/countLevelDetails.action?processId=433332&status=Pending'
results = `curl --negotiate -u: --location-trusted -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt -i -v -k "#{url}"`
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(results))
html_doc.xpath('//table[@id="countLevelDetailsTable"]/tr[starts-with(@id="process-")]/td/a')
#html_doc.xpath("//table/tr/td/a")
#html_doc.search('a').map{ |a| [ a['href'], a.text ] }[0,5]

puts html_doc
```

As you can tell in the ruby file, I have tried multiple ways. Nothing seems to be stripping down the HTML.

I am just manually running the file right now if I can get it to work then it will go into my controller.

I plan to take the list of text of 'P-whatevers' and reduce it down to the first 5 chars, and count them then display them, but right now just stripping down the HTML is all I am working on to do.

Comment: There's no `table/tr`. Either use `table/tbody/tr` or `table//tr`.

Comment: And it's `starts-with(@id, "process-")`, not `starts-with(@id="process-")`

Comment: tried `html_doc.xpath('//table[@id="countLevelDetailsTable"]/tbody/tr[starts-with(@id, "process-")]/td/a/text()')` and tried just the  `//a/text()` still get all the HTML

Comment: Got it to work, had to change `html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(results))` to `html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(results)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a commenter has noted already, what you are looking for is

```
//table[@id="countLevelDetailsTable"]/tbody/tr[starts-with(@id,"process-")]/td/a/text()
```

There are three changes: There is `tbody` in the expression and `starts-with()` has two arguments (it must have two). Finally, there is `text()` at the end (only select the text content of those nodes).

When applied to the document you show, the result is

```
[EMPTY LINE]
P-1-Z100D4
-----------------------
R-1-P110B680
[EMPTY LINE]
```

---

The presence of `tbody` often is a source of confusion because browsers sometimes add a `tbody` element to the DOM tree representation of an HTML document even if it actually isn't there.

Make sure you need all those predicates in the expression. For the input sample you show,

```
//a/text()
```

would also select the correct nodes.